# Fill Gap on sides to Existing Fireplace for Wood Heater

Tags: wood, fireplace, heater

Looking for ideas or a solution. Wanting to fill in the gap on both sides of the existing Fireplace for when we install a wood heater. Have put the cardboard in place to see what the gap would look like. Maybe use cut up bricks or more mortar. Have used mortar already around the fireplace which will eventually be painted.

[image]

Wood heater would leave a gap not only on the sides but the corner of the brick work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you planning to leave the area around the fireplace as the rough mortar finish?

Comment: No the mortar will be painted over

Comment: I actually managed to use some bricks and motor and closed the gap myself. Saved some $$$ and now that it is painted it looks pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Google fireplace insert trim kit and you get things like this:

[image]

Comment: cheers will take a look.

Comment: Man, you and the OP @Steve look close enough to each other (at a quick glance) in your avatars that for a second, I thought you were answering your own question!

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  @freeman not sure I agree but it can happen with the smaller photos/avatars. Cheers